# base_link to base_footprint transform?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use robot_pose_ekf for my navigation stack,
I have done every thing according to [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/2642/robot_pose_ekf-with-an-external-sensor)
but I faced a problem about my transformations!
Robot_pose_ekf is publishing a base_footprint tf, but i dont know how should i connect base_link tf to base_footprint tf. what is the relation between them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12770/base_link-to-base_footprint-transform-?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`base_link` is typically the center of mass or the center of turning for your robot, while `base_footprint` is located at ground level directly below `base_link`. `base_footprint` is a projection of `base_link` onto the ground.

**EDIT**:

If your Center of Mass is 0.5m above the ground, you can publish a transform with parent=`base_footprint` and child=`base_link` with a transform of 0.5z. If you want base_link to be the parent, you would publish -0.5z.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-01-26**:
So how can i implement it? just set its z argument of translation to zero?